# Babylon (B), 2nd step: Can you use this ability only one time?

Tags: 7-wonders

The wonder **Babylon (B)** has a special ability on step 2: You can play your last (7th) card instead of discarding it.

These two questions cover if you'd have to play both cards in the 6th round or if you get a 7th round:

- [Can a resource card be used more than once in a turn when allowed to build more than one structure?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5140/3532)
- [How does Babylons's second stage wonder work for building/discarding your last two cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8039/3532)

I wonder: Can you use this ability in *all* Ages (if built)? Or can you use it only in the Age you built the wonder?

I assumed that you can use it every Age, but then I noted that the special ability of **Olympia (A)**, which can be used in all Ages, has "I, II, III" written on it. This clarification is missing on Bablyon's (B) second step, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You may use it once per age.**  The description of symbols page shows that symbol as (emphasis mine).

> The player can play the last card **of each age** instead of discarding
>   it. This card can be played by paying its cost, discarded to gain 3
>   coins or used in the construction of his or her Wonder.

Comment: Ah, great. In the German translation of the rules it is not that clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain that you can use the ability in all Ages.  I would expect some kind of gloss such as "Once in the game, you may..." if this wasn't the case.

I wonder why Olympia should have a special clarification though.  Perhaps it is to make it clearer that you can only build a free building once per Age (i.e. I, II, III to imply a maximum of three free buildings).  There would be no need to worry that a player might try to play their last card more than once per age, of course...

Comment: Thanks! The explanation for "I, II, III" makes sense to me.