# Timing of Babylon's (B) and Halicarnassus' special abilities?

Tags: 7-wonders

Alice has **Babylon (B)**, Bob has **Halicarnassus (B)**.

Alice has built the 2nd wonder stage, so she is able to play her 7th card.

In the 6th turn:

- Bob builds a stage of his wonder, so he is able to build one card from the discard pile at the end of the turn.
- Alice builds her 6th card and wants to discard her 7th for 3 coins.

Does Alice's card gets added to the discard pile *before* or *after* Bob is allowed to see through it?

In other words: Does Alice get a "real" 7th turn?

---

We already discussed ([here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8039/3532) and [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/5140/3532)) that Alice doesn't have to buy resources for her 6th and 7th card from the same set (so she can buy the same resources again for her 7th card that she bought for her 6th card).

#### Discussion elsewhere

- [boardgamegeek.com: **Halikarnassos and Babylon Interaction**](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/776786/halikarnassos-and-babylon-interaction)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Babylon has a clarification in the rules that says:

> Clariﬁcation :
>   - during the sixth turn, the player can therefore play both cards they have in hand. If the second stage of the Wonder is not built, the
>   Babylon player can then build it on their sixth turn and then play the
>   seventh card instead of discarding it.

Halicarnassus has the following clarification:

> Clariﬁcation : this special action is taken at the end of the turn in
>   which the stage is built. If players discard cards on that turn (for
>   example, during the 6th turn of an age), the player can also choose
>   from among those cards.

I'd say from that that Babylon's power basically all happens "during the sixth turn", and so Halicarnassus can take advantage of any of Babylon's discards.  There isn't really a ghostly extra seventh turn getting created by Babylon's Wonder.