# Babylon B Stage 2 - Purchasing neighbor's resource

Tags: 7-wonders

On the 6th turn, the Babylon player builds their second stage wonder. Their last card in hand requires a Cloth.

Babylon's neighbor built a Loom on their 6th turn. Can the Babylon player, on their 7th turn, purchase Cloth from that neighbor?

This is not a duplicate question. My question specifically asks whether the Babylon player may benefit from the 6th card build by Babylon's neighbors for the 7th card and 7th card only.

All other answers talk about the 7th card benefiting from the 6th card of the Babylon player, or whether the usage state of Babylon's and neighbors resources may be reset for the 7th card's use.

(Also, can does the Babylon player receive gold earned from neighbors between their 6th and 7th card?)

Comment: @Caleb Welcome to Board & Card Games. This question has previously been answered. Please use the link above to find the answer to your question.

Comment: To those voting to close based on the linked question, these seem like different questions. The linked question is asking whether the player can use the same resource twice for Babylon on "turn 6," while this question appears to be asking whether the player can purchase a resource from a neighbor from a resource card that was built on turn 6, prior to the last card being played by the Babylon player.

Comment: Thanks SocioMatt, I asked this question because the other answers do not address this point specifically.

@Todd and Ginji, even the second answer in "Can a resource card be used more than once in a turn when allowed to build more than one structure?" makes no mention specifically about whether the Babylon player may benefit from the 6th card built by their neighbors for their 7th card (and 7th card only).

Comment: I'm confused, and a bit insulted, that the conversation above is going on hours after I gave the definitive answer. I have added the rules booklet page numbers for those who despair of locating the cited rules.

Comment: The second answer in the other thread added 2 hours after my question was asked, mentioned this: "You can build a resource card in the 6th turn, and use it to build the last card (same if a neighbour builds it)."

It only has 1 vote now, but if accepted, that would mean that the answer to my question is "Yes". Could someone confirm and answer on my question too?

Comment: If an answer on a different question is confirmed to be an answer to this question, it is absolutely a duplicate, and should be left closed as redirecting there, possibly with a comment stating which answer worked.

Comment: @Nij, but the question you all are claiming this is a duplicate of isn't even asking the same thing. The answer that works, wasn't even answering that question. The two questions are clearly NOT duplicates. Just because there exists an answer that works doesn't mean the two questions are duplicates. Please read carefully and in full. There is no way anyone who has read both questions can claim this is a duplicate question. BTW, this is the answer that works: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/43721/25263.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what being a duplicate means, and hence the closure. "*[Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers. This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)"*

Answer (score -4):

No. The Babylon player does not get a 7th turn. The wonder allows the player to use both cards on his 6th turn.

"Clarification :
- during the sixth turn, the player can therefore play both cards they have
in hand." Rules to 7 Wonders, page 9.

All actions are simultaneous, so the loom would not exist when the 7th card is played.

"2. Action
Once every player has selected his or her card, they perform their action
simultaneously." Rules to 7 Wonders, page 5.

Comment: Why the down votes. My answer addresses the question and quotes the relevant rule.

Comment: The first quote is often questioned as it is too ambiguous. It had led to the significant discussion in the community and a final clarification by the creator regarding his intent - it is actually to be treated as an additional turn.


The second quote is a very general rule describing the basic operations in the game. As clarified multiple times, the 2 cards to be played due to Babylon B are NOT simultaneous.

Basically, those two rules are too vague, which is why we ask for clarification. Here, you are quoting them as is, disregarding all the discussion that has gone on.

Comment: But you are right, for my specific question, looking plainly at these two rules, the Babylon player does not get a 7th turn. But neither should they get to use the gold from discarding the 6th card, the resources generated from the 6th etc. Which is why, it is not a useful answer.

Comment: The two rules are clear. The designers "clarification" directly contradicts one of them, so it was not a clarification, but rather an informal change in the rules. It has no more standing than any other optional rule. Unless the players have agreed beforehand to use that variant, the rules as written should apply. If you look at the discussions concerning this, no one thinks the rules were ambiguous; they just didn't like the results.

Comment: Then clearly the designer made a mistake with his original wording of the rules. I want to play it the way he envisions it, also, the way that makes the most sense, and is the most balanced and most importantly, intuitive and fun.